# Editing row of one dataframe appears to affect another? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a bit of a strange issue, where I must be making some sort of mistake.

My script is as follows: Create one dataframe of 4 rows and 3 columns, full of random values. Then create a second dataframe which is equal to the first one, and then in the second df, change the values of the second row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create random df
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,3))

#Create a second df which is the same as df1
df2 = df1

#Viewing them both, the look the same
df1
df2

#Now edit row #1 of df2
df2.iloc[1:2] = [[0 , 0, 1]]

#Now viewing them both, both df1 and df2 have row #1 as 0, 0, 1
```

I thought that df2 = df1 would be a one time assignment and the two dataframes would be entirely separate from then on?

Comment: Need `df2 = df1.copy()` for new object ;)

Comment: Thanks jezrael - stupid me. Can you post as an answer and I can mark as solved?

Comment: It is a general problem with mutable structures in Python, see for instance this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/5276797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new mutable object in python (here `DataFrame`) need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df2 = df1.copy()
```

Better explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/2901002).